# How to share Areas across projects in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I need share some controllers and views in two or more projects because I need the same logic in the backend, but I don't want duplicate the code.

In Asp Net standard I can create nuget a package of an area (this is not so beautiful solution but it worked) 
https://retinalamps.wordpress.com/2013/10/12/creating-an-asp-net-mvc-nuget-package

In the Asp Net Core Web Application I can't create package. I would like to find a good practice solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would take advantage of organizing it as `Feature` [slices](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/mt763233.aspx) in ASP MVC Core, this would save a lot of time down the road, I would recommend it in 2 steps.

1. First, **organize**/put it an area called `Features` splices [MSDN ref](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/mt763233.aspx). *wire it up as in the article and well explained.*

   `// you're telling ASP that you've other Feature areas that it should look
     public IEnumerable<string> ExpandViewLocations(ViewLocationExpanderContext context,
     IEnumerable<string> viewLocations)
     {
     // Error checking removed for brevity
     var controllerActionDescriptor =
       context.ActionContext.ActionDescriptor as ControllerActionDescriptor;
     string featureName = controllerActionDescriptor.Properties["feature"] as string;
     foreach (var location in viewLocations)
     {
       yield return location.Replace("{3}", featureName);
     }
    }`
2. Second, ***embed*** Features in a
   `Shared project` or `Portable Libraries`. I have attached links on
   how to do this from R. Williams and MSDN.

In summary, since you already have it in a common area consider it to be a feature and embed it inside a [portable lib or a Shared Project](http://rion.io/2017/03/22/sharing-is-caring-using-shared-projects-in-asp-net/). *A nice article by R. Williams.*

[image]

Comment: Your suggestions worked! Only one things for the views files, I made a small ugly compromise. I don't want compile the view I wrote a x-copy script to copy all views in the main project from a Shared Projects (I will use shared project) / Library.

Comment: @Evilripper glad it worked, feel free to edit my answer :)

Answer (score 1):

When we had to solve this problem seven years ago, it was `svn:externals` feature that did it, and it works flawlessly to this day. I understand that similar feature in `git` is called `submodules`.

Comment: It seems like a good solution but I prefer to use a shared library.